# Extract folder content using tar?

Tags: linux, directory, tar

There is a [similar question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35311/how-do-you-extract-a-single-folder-from-a-large-tar-gz-archive).

If I understand correctly, the first answer indicates that we cannot extract the contents of a folder, but only a specific file from a folder?

The second answer uses the `--directory` option.  This looks to be precisely what I want, however this does not extract files from a certain directory within the archive, but instead outputs the files to the directory indicated by the `--directory`option.

When I tarred up my folder tar included the entire path from the root directory down.  So it has `home/ole/folder/thestuff`.  I want to extract `folder/thestuff` into the current folder that I'm in without including `home/ole`.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can always follow the tar extraction with `mv home/ole/folder .` and then `rmdir home/ole; rmdir home`.

Comment: Yes that's what I have been doing.  I'm also going to use the -C option in the future to leave the `home/ole` folder off the path, but I was thinking that there has to be a way to just extract a folder?

Comment: @steve ... I tried the `--directory` option which ended up totally nuking the updated content I had in the original sub folder ... ooops :)

Comment: If it's not possible, that's cool, it's an easy work around ... But if it is possible then I'd like to understand how ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If I understand correctly, the first answer indicates that we cannot extract the contents of a folder, but only a specific file from a folder?

No, it's talking about relative vs absolute filenames.  The difference between `/some/path` and `some/path`

Take a look at the contents of your tarfile `tar tf file`.  You can't specify the folder as `/path/to/folder`, when it's listed as `path/to/folder`.

There's no problem giving (the correct) folder to extract.

- List the files that will be extracted

`tar tf file.tar path/to/folder`

- Extract the files
  (into the current directory)

`tar xf file.tar path/to/folder`

As an example:

Check the contents:

```
$ tar tf ../test.tar
a/
a/3
a/2
a/1
b/
b/3
b/2
b/1
```

Extract folder a

```
$ tar xf ../test.tar a
```

See what it extracted

```
$ find .
.
./a
./a/3
./a/2
./a/1
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I could do this:

tar -xvzf archive.tar.gz --strip-components=2

This removes `home/ole` from the path, and extract everything below that in the archive into the current directory.