# Is it possible to obtain .tar from .tar.bz2?

Tags: tar, compression

I need to [extract a specific folder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35315/334715) from `.tar.bz2` (34G). The issue is that it takes 1 hour. I guess that this is due to the compression. I guess that w/o compression extraction of a specific folder will be faster.

Hence, is it possible to obtain `.tar` from `.tar.bz2`?

Answer (score 5):

If your question is whether it is possible to decompress the related part for the specific folder, bzip2 doesn't index its compressed data, which means there's no way to jump directly to a specific byte in the decompressed data without processing what's before it. `tar` is also a sequential format without a central index.

---

If, however, your question is whether you can amortise the work beforehand by decompressing once and extracting a single folder multiple times, then yes, that is possible using the `bzip2` command:

```bash
bzip2 -d foo.tar.bz2
```

This will then decompress to `foo.tar`.

Comment: And this is not limited to bzip2.

Comment: Bzip2 *does* use independent blocks for compression, see https://sourceware.org/bzip2/manual/manual.html#recovering

Comment: But that doesn't help, because `tar` has no index up front. To find the part you want to decompress, you need to decompress the whole compressed file: everything befroe the file to know where it starts, and everything after the file, because `tar` allows for keeping the same file around multiple times, so that you the "later" copy of the same file overwrites the earlier one. Only when you decompressed the last file you can be sure there's no further copies of the file.

Comment: you can also do `bzcat foo.tar.bz2 | tar -xvf - `

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks! Not sure why I mistakenly thought that bzip2 has interblock dependencies. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess that w/o compression extraction of a specific folder will be faster.

Sadly, that's impossible, due to the nature of compression and the tar file format. To know where a file is, you need to decompress the whole compressed file: everything before the file to know where it starts, and everything after the file, because `tar` allows for keeping the same file around multiple times, so that you the "later" copy of the same file overwrites the earlier one. Only when you decompressed the last file you can be sure there's no further copies of the file.

So, the only thing you can do is decompress faster, using the parallel bzip2 implementation `pbzip2` (you might need to install that first!)

```bash
pbzip2 -d -c large.tar.bz2 | tar xf - path/to/specific/folder
```

For future archiving: there's things that compress as well or nearly as well as `bzip2` and allow for *much* faster decompression. So, if this problem occurs more often, it might make sense to re-archive the whole thing using something that allows for faster decompression, and for selective extraction without having to decompress the whole archive; something like

```bash
pbzip2 -d -c large.tar.bz2 | sqfstar -comp zstd -xattrs -Xcompression-level=8 large.sqsh
```

(In addition to `pbzip`, you'll need `sqfstar`, which on most systems (fedora-based, debian-based) is part of the `squashfs-tools` package)

Bonus: these archives can directly be mounted, but you can also use a command line tool to get individual files from them.

```bash
udisksctl loop-setup -f large.sqsh # note the displayed block device name
udisksctl mount -b /dev/loop1234   # only if not automounted by previous command
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract a specific folder from file.tar.bz2 and then put it in the own target path directory:

```
tar -C /own/target_path/ -xvf file.tar.bz2 path/specific_folder_from_file_tar_bz2
```

The specific folder will be decompress in /own/target_path

Regards...